# Range filter for custom attribute in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, php, filter

I need a range filter for the custom attribute (weight) like price range filter

I used the below URL for the price range filter

```
domain/rings?&price=20000-30000 - working
```

same as that I used for the weight range filter

```
domain/rings?&weight=-400-500 - not working
```

how can I solve this issue?

Please suggest any idea to filter weight range

Comment: what do you mean filter is not working ? does not not display results or any error ?

Comment: all products are listing

Comment: have you noticed that your wieght filter is starting with -400 ? is it intentional ?

Comment: Is the minus before 400 a typo? `weight=-400-500`